# Developing a wordpress.com shortcode

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I am looking to develop a shortcode that all wordpress.com users can use.

Should I proceed with developing a plugin? I know users on wordpress.org can use the plugin but I am confused on how to make wordpress.com users use the shortcode as wordpress.com does not let the users to install a plugin. Is it done in the background by wordpress.com by looking up the plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything related to adding code to wordpress.com you should contact [automatic](http://automattic.com/).